# Голосовые помошники (Яндекс Алиса) - как происходит связка ответов в диалог?

Tags: яндекс-алиса

Не скажу, что не понимаю как работает Алиса у Яндекса с ее навыками и подобные помощники, но НЕ дошел до оптимального решения как выстраивать диалог.
Поправьте если я не знаю или ошибаюсь в чем-то. Сейчас, весь процесс по сути это вопрос-ответ с использованием TTS и обратно. Чтобы выстроить диалог - когда Алиса помнит, что было сказано-отвечено ранее, это сохранение предыдущей информации на основе фактически поиска-выделения ключевых слов. Но сохранение этих результатов ответа на основе выделения ключевых слов и т.д. порождает громоздкие конструкции в языке, на котором пишется скрипт(например PHP) и чем сложнее диалог, нужно анализировать больше и больше предыдущих результатов чтобы создать некую связность, когда ты пытаешься симулировать некий аналог кратковременной памяти человека. В итоге получаем некую конструкцию с кучей условий и ветвлений. Есть ли возможность реализовывать сложные диалоги более простыми способами или конструкциями? Возможно я просто не знаю что уже есть готовые решения.

Comment: представьте диалог как древовидную систему меню (на самом деле это граф с множественными связями).  у вас есть точка в дереве (id) где сейчас находиться пользователь, для каждой точки в БД есть набор возможных переходов в другие точки дерева. Выбор ключевых слов проводит нас по одному из таких путей, меняя текущую точку. сам скрипт - это выбор следующего узла дерева по предыдущему узлу и ключевым словам. он достаточно прост. главное это наполнение справочника-дерева для него

Comment: Есть ли смысл в таком случае использовать для хранения структуру данных типа куча? Как древовидную структуру.

Comment: А как куча относиться к дереву ? Я предполагаю что дерево в БД и скорее всего в виде ссылки на родителя в дочерней записи

Answer (score 2):

Все такие помощники работают на машинном обучении. Алиса работает на основе двух моделей: одна генерирует потанциальные "ответы", а другая подбирает наиболее подходящий "ответ" "из прошлого". И результат строится на комбинации этих двух моделе, а как, уже зависит от метрики, которая вшивается в алгоритм: например "длина диалога" или "поддержка контекста"(с использованием какой-нибудь функции подсчета качества его поддержания)